# Proof that a set $C$ is convex $\iff$ its intersection with any line is convex

Tags: proof-verification, convex-analysis

I'm working through Convex Optimization by Boyd, and want to check my answer to the above question. Is the following reasoning correct?

Let $L$ be an arbitrary line.

For $\Rightarrow$:

**Case 1**: $C \cap L = \emptyset$

This is convex by definition.

**Case 2**:$C \cap L \neq  \emptyset$

$x,y \in C$ and $x,y \in L \implies \lambda x + (1- \lambda)y \in C$ (by assumption) for $\lambda \in [0,1]$

Also, $\lambda x + (1- \lambda)y$ lies on the line segment between $x,y$, which is in $L$.

For $\Leftarrow$:

I decided to try proof by contradiction:

We are given that $C\cap L$ is convex for all lines. Assume $C$ is not convex.

Our assumption implies $\exists x,y \in C$ and $\lambda_0\in [0,1]: \lambda_0 x + (1-\lambda_0)y \notin C$. However, the line formed by $ax+(1-a)y,\;\;a\in \mathbb{R}$ will have a nonempty intersection with $C$ and yet the resulting set will not be convex (i.e, it will not contain $\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y$). Hence, we must negate our assumption, which means that $C$ must be convex.

I think this is correct as per this question:[Poof- A function is convex iff it is convex when restricted to a any line that intersects its domain.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1852844/poof-a-function-is-convex-iff-it-is-convex-when-restricted-to-a-any-line-that-i)

I also justified it by noting that if we let $A$ be the proposition "$C \cap L$ is convex for all lines $L$", and $B$ be the proposition "$C$ is convex" then what I showed was:

$A \wedge \neg B \implies \neg A$ which is equivalent to:

$\neg (A \wedge \neg B) \vee \neg A$ which (via DeMorgan's Laws) is $\neg A \vee B$.

This last statement can also be expressed $A \implies B$, hence I think I've shown the converse.

Comment: I think your proof is good. In statement _Our assumption implies ..._ it's better to add **for a $\lambda_0\in\mathbb{R}$**.

Comment: @MyGlasses thanks. I added your statement, although since I'm working with convex sets, I restricted lambda to the unit interval.

Comment: No, This $\lambda$ is $\exists\lambda$ which $0<\lambda<1$.

Comment: @MyGlasses Oh...yes! Thanks! It wont be true for ALL lambdas.

Comment: I can't remember on which thread, but this question has already been asked (and answered) here on SE in the past...

Comment: @dohmatob I did link to a related question in my post. If you find an exact duplicate, please do provide the link and I'll notify the moderators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So your proof is correct, but a little confusing -- especially the second part. It's easier to do directly instead of via contradiction. A little simplification:

$\Leftarrow$: Let $x,y\in C$ and let $\lambda\in[0,1]$. We wish to prove $\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y\in C$.

Let $L$ be the line through $x$ and $y$. $x$ and $y$ are in $C\cap L$. By convexity of $C\cap L$, we have that $\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y\in C\cap L$ and hence clearly $\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y\in C$.

Comment: Thanks! Your approach is certainly more succinct.

Comment: don't you also have to show that if $C \cap L$ is not convex then $C$ cannot be convex (to satisfy IFF)?