# help understanding conclusion of proof that $-f(Z)=-log|Z|$ is convex

Tags: convex-analysis, positive-definite

Need help understanding the conclusion of the proof [here](https://piazza.com/class_profile/get_resource/is58gs5cfya7ft/itawqt5undn2bv)

How does $-g(t)=-log|X+tV|$ (where $\textbf X, X+tV$ are positive definite) being convex prove that $-f(Z)=-log|Z|$ is convex, Z positive definite nxn matrix?

How do they get from (I wrote this, but I think it's the correct definition of concavity)

$$\begin{split}-log|X+(\lambda t_1+(1-\lambda)t_2)V|&\le-\lambda log|X+t_1V|-(1-\lambda)log|X+t_2V| \text { to}\\
-log|\lambda Z_1+(1-\lambda)Z_2|&\le-\lambda log|Z_1|-(1-\lambda)log |Z_2|\end{split}$$

Steps:

$$\begin{split}-log|X+\lambda t_1 V+(1-\lambda)t_2V|&\le-\lambda log|X+t_1V|-(1-\lambda)log|X+t_2V|\\
-log|X+Z|&\le-\lambda log|X+Z_1|-(1-\lambda)log|X+Z_2|\\\end{split}$$

Comment: This is an elementary property of convex functions: $f$ is convex iff $g(t) := f(x + tv)$ is convex for all $v$ and $x$. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1852844/a-function-is-convex-iff-it-is-convex-when-restricted-to-any-line) for a proof.